# Create and stylize a table with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have [this JSON](https://gis.massimilianomoraca.it/geoserver/ComuneDiParete/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=application%2Fjson&LAYER=strutturale_puc&SCALE=27555.61305347797) from which I need to create a table. This table must be a legend for a webmap created with OpenLayers 6. As you have seen the JSON comes from Geoserver.

Below my code:

```
let updateLegend = function(resolution) {
  let graphicUrl = strutturale_puc.getSource().getLegendUrl(
    resolution,
    {'FORMAT': 'application/json'}
  );
  
  if(graphicUrl) {
    fetch(graphicUrl)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        const legendData = jsonData.Legend[0].rules;

        const table = document.getElementById("table");
        const footer = table.createTFoot();

        legendData.forEach((value) => {

           cellStroke = value.symbolizers[0].Polygon.stroke;
           cellFill = value.symbolizers[0].Polygon.fill;
           cellContent = value.name;

           const tableRaw = footer.insertRow(value);
           tableRaw.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<td style="border: 4px solid ' + cellStroke + '; background-color: ' + cellFill + '; max-width: 10px;"></td>';
           tableRaw.insertCell(1).innerHTML = '<td style="border: none;">' + cellContent + '</td>';

           console.log(tableRaw);
         });
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      });
   }
```

The table is inside a div:

```
<div class="" id="legend">
  <table class="table" id="table">

  </table>
</div>
```

My problem is that I can't see any style when the table is created, I can see only the text(`cellContent`). For me is strange because if I use this:

```
<div class="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 4px solid #791919; background-color: #A71C1C; max-width: 10px;"></td>
      <td style="border: none;">Item</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I can see all correctly. What I wrong?

Comment: why don't you  use real css ?

Comment: What do you mean? Something like `mystyle.css` instead of inline style? If yes, because I can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.insertCell` creates a `<td>` element, inserts it into the table, and returns a reference to it ([per the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)).

You then set the contents of that `<td>` to contain another `<td>` where you add the styling rule.

So now you essentially have:

```
<td>
    <td style="border: 4px solid #791919; background-color: #A71C1C; max-width: 10px;"></td>
</td>
```

You can only have a `<td>` tag within a `<tr>` tag, so the browser removes the internal `<td>` tag (along with its styling), and adds its contents to the original `<td>`.

---

To solve the issue, you need to add the styling to the `<td>` that it makes for you. For example:

```
let firstCell = tableRaw.insertCell(0);
firstCell.setAttribute("style", 'border: 4px solid ' + cellStroke + '; background-color: ' + cellFill + '; max-width: 10px;');
firstCell.innerHTML = "";
```

---

Code quality notes:

- You should use CSS classes rather that inline styles.
- You should use template literals rather than inline string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you, but how I can use `cellStroke = value.symbolizers[0].Polygon.stroke;` instead of `#791919` with your example? This is my problem, I need to get cells style from JSON.

Comment: Use CSS. I mean, you _can_ say `firstCell.cellStroke = value.symbolizers[0].Polygon.stroke;` I think, but it's deprecated --- we're not in the 90s anymore.

Comment: I know that we aren't in the 90s but unfotunatly, in this situation, I must adopt old solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair, legacy endpoints are a pain. That being said, 1) `setAttribute` function just takes in a normal string, so you can just do what you were already doing with the inline CSS, 2) you could _definetly_ make this better given what you have, for example you could move most of that code to an external CSS file, and then set the `cellFill` as a CSS custom variable on the element.

Comment: Anyway, my updated answer should solve your problem, I believe :)

Comment: Hope I have a possibility to upgrade this project to the current technologies as soon as possible. Thank you :)